# Reducing to reduced echelon form in linear algebra seems to do so many useful things - what gives? Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

What's the underlying thing about reducing a matrix to reduced echelon form that solves so many things for us?

Some determinations that can be from reducing to reduced echelon form:

- Testing linear dependency
- Seeing if a matrix has an inverse
- Solving a system of linear equations
- Finding the number of free parameters in a system of linear equations
- Finding row and column rank

I know why it can determine each *individual* thing, but there seems to be some underlying essence behind it all. It seems like a *very* convenient algorithm, so there must be something about it I'm missing that explains why it can explain so many things about a matrix. My guess is that it reduces the matrix down to its basis which may determine the rest by analyzing the basis, but other than that, not sure. What gives?

ADDENDUM:

I've been told in a comment that "reducing to RREF reveals the basis of the row-space". How can a matrix have a different row space and column space simultaneously? What does that mean about matrices, exactly?

Comment: One way to think about it is that the RREF form of a matrix is its canonical form; any two matrices that have the same RREF form will have the same solution set when used in a linear equation Ax=b. So putting in RREF form somehow uncovers the "underlying" form of the matrix, in much the same way that say a Jordan Canonical form does.

Comment: The real "star" of the show are the matrix eigenvalues; and I would argue that the *most canonical* form of a matrix is its spectral decomposition (or SVD, if non-Hermitian). The row-echelon form happens to reveal just enough about the eigenvalues (i.e. whether and how many are zero) to answer the questions on your list.

Comment: You’ve got the gist of it: row-reduction finds a basis for the row space of the matrix, which lets you deduce a lot of information because of the relationships among the four fundamental subspaces.

Comment: @amd Can you elaborate on the "four fundamental subspaces"?